# How to stop MediaRecorder after certain time in Android?

Tags: android, camera, android-mediarecorder, android-camera2

I want to stop recording a video after a certain time e.g. 5 seconds.
Do you know how to do that with a `MediaRecorder`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a handler to step the recording after that time.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        recorder.stop();
    }
}, DELAY);
```

Regarding the timer:

```
int t = 0;
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.formatted_time, t));
        if(++t<10) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

Where formatted_time is something like that:

```
<string android:name="formatted_time">%d seconds</string>
```

Comment: Is there a way to write `every second` something to the log? So I know how many second already have been recorded.

Comment: The same as above just you use 1000 as delay and you update an TextView instead.

Comment: I want to record a video for about 10 sec and every second I want to print the current second. How would the code look like?

Comment: This is a different question. Please ask it separately I will answer it there.

Comment: It's basically the same so it would be easier if you answer it here.

Comment: I see that a little differnt but here you are

Answer (score 1):

```
mCountdowntimer=new CountDownTimer(countdownPeriod, 1000) {//countdown Period =5000

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                textView.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() {

                 mediaplayer.stop(); }

        }.start();
```

and must not forget to call release(); after calling stop();

Comment: So in your example it's 1 second?

Comment: put "countdownPeriod=5000" for 5 second.